# Is there a way to hand off a TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, imap

We are creating a web app that sits between a mail client and mail server handling the IMAP calls (we care mostly about SELECT and LIST). But when the user does a FETCH, we would prefer that the returned data not go through our server, to reduce our bandwidth usage.

Is there a way we can hand the request off to be direct? Or change it in such a way that the response goes direct to the originator?

(We're doing this in C# although I doubt that has any bearing on the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would not work, for three reasons:

1. IMAP is asynchronous and can have multiple command in flight at one time, so the client could issue a `FETCH` and then issue other commands, including `LIST`, while waiting for `FETCH` to complete.
2. even if the client were sending only one command at a time, you would still have to keep monitoring the connections to know when the `FETCH` has completed so you can switch back to your `SELECT/LIST` handling.
3. your app has two separate TCP connections - one between itself and the client, and one between itself and the server.  There is no way to link those connections together to remove your app from that chain.  If your app wants to drop out, it has to close those connections.

So no, you cannot "hand off" the data.  As long as your app is connected to the client and server, **all** data must flow through your app, whether you process it or not.  That is just the nature of how a TCP proxy/tunnel operates.

Comment: That is my understanding too, but I figured better to ask in case there was something I didn't know (I'm competent at sockets, but in no way an expert). I was hoping there was a way to somehow make the response a direct connection back. Oh well... Thank you.